# Why duplicated "title" textbox on Wagtail Admin portal?

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

with below customized `Page` model,

```
class PostDetail(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField("body"),
    ]

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel("title"),
        FieldPanel("body"),
    ]
```

I did not add `title = models.Char()` because `PostDetail` will inherit all attributes (including `title`) from wagtail built-in `Page` model.

But when I tried to add a `Post Detail` page, I saw duplicated `title` fields. why is that?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FieldPanel("title")` is already defined in `Page.content_panels`, so `Page.content_panels + [FieldPanel("title")]` defines it twice.

Comment: according to source code, https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/main/wagtail/core/models/__init__.py,  `content_panels = []` is configured in `class Page()`. So I expected `Page.content_panels` to be empty?

Comment: They get set up in https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/ca15f2d991d4d35f1dfc194bfa81c99504574e15/wagtail/admin/edit_handlers.py#L910-L938 - it can't be done in the wagtail.core.models module because that would create a circular dependency between the wagtail.core and wagtail.admin apps.